# when you only sing in F#

Tags: piano, chord-theory, voice

Tim Minchin sang this song:

It is called "when you only sing in F#". Apparently the song is really funny. If you know music. I do not know music, hence I am asking here: what is the joke?

He sings "I am playing in F major but I am singing in F#". First of all: is that true, does he really sing the entire song in F# while playing in F major?

And is that some hard thing to do? Or why is this funny?

I hope a kind soul will help me understand the fun.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I feel it's a better fit for MusicFans. However, there is a good case to be made that this belongs here, both as an analysis question and a performance question.

Comment: Really, six up votes for an off topic question?

Comment: I'm **triggered**  , because right now I'm working up my part (cello) for Franck's  Symphonic Variations (piano & orch), which **is** in F# .  It's tempting to tune all 4 strings a half-step high :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - you mean there isn't a capo available for cellos (celli)??

Comment: @tim LOL sadly capos only adjust the open pitch as you know.  (We don't have frets so "just count a different fret number" doesn't work either)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The joke is that he sings in F#, *even though it sounds bad*, just because he prefers singing in F#.

He does not sing the whole song in F# while playing in F*.  That *would* be very difficult to do, but he does not do it.  He plays in F while singing in F, so it sounds good.  Until that F#... that's the punchline.  It sounds bad, and the audience laughs.

*Most of the song is actually in D minor, which shares all the same notes as F, but that's a technicality that doesn't really matter as far as the joke is concerned.

Comment: The joke goes beyond simply sounding bad. It's a spoof of musicians — particularly singers — who insist on playing or singing songs in a specific key, either because "they have the right emotion" or because it fits their voice/instrument better. I cannot tell you how many times I played in pit orchestras and had to transpose from G major to G flat to accommodate the singer. Or jam sessions where someone tried to show off by playing a well-known song in an obscure key.

Comment: Well yes, there is that, I don't think that's what really made the audience laugh though

Comment: There are a lot of people in that audience.

Comment: It's the way Les Dawson would play out of tune. Some notes were just a semitone out and that's more than enough. A party piece of mine is to play a piece where the l.h. plays in C#, while the r.h. is in C. Much easier than singing out of tune (for some...)

Comment: @Tim: Do you happen to have a recording of your C/C# piece?

Comment: @EricDuminil - no - it's a secret  - for now!

Comment: I have to dv. He doesn't sing *any* of the song**in** F#. He happens to sing a few *notes* **on** F#, that's all.

Comment: @Tim Ok, fair, a few F#s is not enough to establish a new key center, but at this point our analysis is separated from what made the joke funny in the first place.  I get that you don't find it funny, but lots of people do, and the question was "why is this funny?"

Comment: @Aaron   A shift from G to Gb may seem trivial and merely annoying to the musicians, but it can make a lot of difference when the song contains a 'money note' for the vocalist!

Answer (score 5):

Ironically, he's not singing in F initially, nor F♯ when he sings that he is.

The song's far more in Dm, and the F♯ note he sings is actually the major 3rd of D - yes, it's an F♯,, but he's certainly not 'singing **in** F♯. Which limits the funniness of the piece, unfortunately.

EDIT: trying to find why musos may find this funny. There have been many occasions when I've encountered singers who've said 'I only sing in F♯ (or whatever key)'. Most musos will understand that it's actually a statement which doesn't hold water. For a couple of reasons.

Songs' range can vary depending far more on their highest and lowest notes, which are in fact independent to the key they're in.

Most folk have a range of more than an octave, whilst a lot of songs span only one. So changing key, up or down, will be possible for most singers - albeit a tone or two, so 'only in F♯' doesn't ring true.

Les Dawson (British comedian) was an accomplished pianist, but he usually incorporated in his act renditions of popular songs, which he expected the audience to join in with, but spectacularly made horrible mistakes with some notes - very cleverly worked out - while retaining his inimitable smile, as if there was nothing wrong. Now *that* was funny!

Tim has (probably) taken this and the first reason to write (?) and sing the song. But from maybe a slightly different viewpoint. He sings those F♯ notes against the F♮ played in the D minor chord, which is discordant. Had it been the other way round, it'd just sound Bluesy. Hence the reference to F♯. Musos would appreciate this, and lots would think it was actually difficult to do - it's not, but it's effective. But I still say it's a misnomer!

EXTRA EDIT: it'll probably resonate with some musos my experiences when a singer says 'I sing in x key'. You play a chord for that key, and they then proceed singing in a completely different one. Yes, sometimes F♯...

Comment: Yes, though it does need to be mentioned that Dm is the [relative minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_key) of F, which makes it close enough to being “in F”. I reckon he tried various ways of implementing the whole idea, and found Dm to be the most practical and/or most jarring. It certainly makes it a bit easier to perform: just sing a Picardy third but stubbornly happer out the chords in minor against it.

Comment: @leftaroundabout - yes, I'm happy with him 'being in F', but he's never 'in F#' - or its relative minor, for that matter. Singing in a key a semitone above what's being played is reserved for pub singers.

Comment: He actually added a text note over the video on the first F♯ saying 'it's actually D min' It does close on F though.

Comment: @TetsujinI missed that, although it's not unknown for songs to modulate between relatives - or in this case, maybe, parallels. Or both...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of why it's funny.

Comment: @Aaron - personally, I don't find it funny anyway. It's feeding false information, just sounds out of tune, and doesn't actually do what it says on the tin. Hence the use of 'ironically'. I'm sure not everyone laughs at it - same as not everyone laughs at some of my jokes. OP doesn't get it either, even though he 'sings out of tune'. How does one explain why a joke is funny? (Especially when one doesn't find it any more than pathetic). Your dv?

Comment: From the standpoint of what musicians find funny about music this is a total dud, I agree. He holds an F# note over a Dm chord. The rest of the time he is singing in D minor. At the very end he sings an F# over an F chord which is so sharp it is practically a G. It is further made un-funny by the fact that the entire piece is played with a orchestra, basically condoning all the inaccuracies. Sing an entire song in F# while playing in F and I will be rolling around on the floor laughing, not to mention incredibly impressed!

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy I did laugh when he did it but it's still ridiculous. I do not find it musical or entertaining though. Just kinda stupid that he would do it... but look what he does to his eyes. Anything to stand out. Not really that musical overall. Better piano playing than singing. Just kinda stupid stuff. Not sure why an orchestra would waste their time... and not like they added anything of value. Think about how many people there wasted their time... not just the audience but all the musicians, production team, etc. Hopefully there was more going on.

Comment: He is singing and F# over a Dm chord. This actually makes it a D chord and the F is then a #9(although given the context the #9 has been so emphasized as to make the F# sound like a dim4)... but his singing off key and badly doesn't help. If one is going to sing a dim4 it has to be done tonally at least. It's holding it out and that is obviously what makes it sound terrible and, of course, intentionally done... but stupid none the less. If someone wants to laugh at some stupid things go to a comedy show.